# unfortunately button has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, button

In eclipse there are no red errors, but when I try to run application it say unfortunately button has stopped.

LogCat

```
11-09 10:13:33.134: D/AndroidRuntime(1007): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    11-09 10:13:33.144: D/AndroidRuntime(1007): CheckJNI is ON
    11-09 10:13:33.184: D/dalvikvm(1007): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:33.204: D/dalvikvm(1007): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:33.264: D/dalvikvm(1007): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:33.264: D/dalvikvm(1007): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:34.124: D/AndroidRuntime(1007): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    11-09 10:13:34.184: D/AndroidRuntime(1007): Shutting down VM
    11-09 10:13:34.204: D/dalvikvm(1007): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 466K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 15ms
    11-09 10:13:34.204: D/dalvikvm(1007): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    11-09 10:13:34.815: D/AndroidRuntime(1020): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    11-09 10:13:34.815: D/AndroidRuntime(1020): CheckJNI is ON
    11-09 10:13:34.884: D/dalvikvm(1020): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:34.904: D/dalvikvm(1020): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:34.964: D/dalvikvm(1020): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:34.964: D/dalvikvm(1020): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    11-09 10:13:36.064: D/AndroidRuntime(1020): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
    11-09 10:13:36.134: I/ActivityManager(151): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.bogdanskoric.button/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 1020
    11-09 10:13:36.144: W/WindowManager(151): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
    11-09 10:13:36.194: D/dalvikvm(1030): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    11-09 10:13:36.204: D/AndroidRuntime(1020): Shutting down VM
    11-09 10:13:36.224: I/AndroidRuntime(1020): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
    11-09 10:13:36.244: D/dalvikvm(1020): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 77% free 489K/2048K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 29ms
    11-09 10:13:36.254: I/ActivityManager(151): Start proc com.bogdanskoric.button for activity com.bogdanskoric.button/.MainActivity: pid=1030 uid=10046 gids={1028}
    11-09 10:13:36.254: D/jdwp(1020): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
    11-09 10:13:36.254: D/dalvikvm(1020): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    11-09 10:13:36.334: I/Choreographer(248): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    11-09 10:13:36.714: E/Trace(1030): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    11-09 10:13:37.234: I/Choreographer(248): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    11-09 10:13:37.324: D/AndroidRuntime(1030): Shutting down VM
    11-09 10:13:37.324: W/dalvikvm(1030): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bogdanskoric.button/com.bogdanskoric.button.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #11: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #11: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5458)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5594)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1099)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:956)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:70)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.bogdanskoric.button.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    11-09 10:13:37.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     ... 11 more
    11-09 10:13:37.364: W/ActivityManager(151):   Force finishing activity com.bogdanskoric.button/.MainActivity
    11-09 10:13:37.374: W/WindowManager(151): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010
    11-09 10:13:37.894: W/ActivityManager(151): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4159fd60 com.bogdanskoric.button/.MainActivity}
    11-09 10:13:38.234: I/Choreographer(248): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

MainActivty

```
package com.bogdanskoric.button;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener 
{

Button buttonE;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        buttonE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonE.setOnClickListener (this);
    }

    private void buttonClick ()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.bogdanskoric.button.EmocijeActivityMainActivity"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        switch (v.getId())

        {
        case R.id.button:
        buttonClick();
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bogdanskoric.button.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EmocijeActivityMainActivity

```
package com.bogdanskoric.button;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class EmocijeActivityMainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.emocije_activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.emocije_activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Button manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bogdanskoric.button"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EmocijeActivityMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.bogdanskoric.button.EmocijeActivityMainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFOULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all :  **Binary XML file line #11: You must supply a `layout_width` attribute.**

Basically the error is that you have not defined any `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the xml attribute of TextView...

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... Other Attributes
/>
```

Comment: Tnx a lot! Now it works, but when I press button there are no onother activity. Maybe I writen wrong activity (11-09 10:47:53.110: E/AndroidRuntime(618): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.bogdanskoric.button.EmocijeActivityMainActivity })

Comment: Try this Change this `startActivity(new Intent ("com.bogdanskoric.button.EmocijeActivityMainActivity"));` to this: `startActivity(new Intent (getApplicationContext(), com.bogdanskoric.button.EmocijeActivityMainActivity.class));`

Comment: Tnx Nadeem lqbal! I fixed problem tiping  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmocijeActivityMainActivity.class);
startActivity(i); This is similar what you wrote me. Tnx agen :)